# Have Paperclip make raster thumbnails of vector images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, thumbnails, eps

I'm working on a site that uses [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to attach images to some records.  Currently, all of the images are jpeg, and paperclip generates png thumbnails that appear in browser views.

We would like to add support for [eps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) images as well.  Without making any changes, uploading and downloading eps images already works, but the thumbnails are not generated.  Paperclip does not log any errors, it just fails to generate a thumbnail.

```
has_attached_file :drawing, :styles => { :thumb => ["64x64#", :png] }, :convert_options => { :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" }
validates_attachment :drawing
```

What needs to be added to generate thumbnails of eps files?

Comment: I know nothing about paperclip but Imagemagick uses Ghostscript when working with pdf files and that could be your problem? I thought there would have been an error thrown somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be a problem with the type spoofing detection.  Paperclip seems to get confused when different sources of file type information disagree.

The solution in my case was to create file named `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` with this content:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  eps: "application/octet-stream"
}
```

I also tried editing the model to add `validates_attachment_content_type` and `validates_attachment_file_name`, neither of which had any noticeable effect.

I would understand if Paperclip didn't trust that the attachment was an acceptable type and refused to attach it, I don't understand why it doesn't trust the type so it attaches the file but doesn't create the thumbnail.